# Rendering progressively higher resolution images, canvas won't show any but the last image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get my script to render progressively higher-resolution images and substitute them into my canvas as they become available.  Right now, nothing gets rendered to the canvas until the script has reached the highest resolution it plans to render at.

[Here's where I'm currently at](https://jsfiddle.net/25z6gdsv/1/) (jsfiddle).  The basic structure is:

```
$(function() {

    window.onresize = function() {
        resizeCanvas();
    };

    resizeCanvas();

});

function resizeCanvas() {
    // set canvas css to fill body

    canvas.width = 18;
    canvas.height = canvas.width * aspectRatio;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");        
    drawMandlebrot(...);

    while (2 * canvas.width < $(window).width()) {
        canvas.width *= 2;
        canvas.height *= 2;

        drawMandlebrot(...);
    }
}

function drawMandlebrot(...) {
    var preCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    preCanvas.width = canvas.width;
    preCanvas.height = canvas.height;
    var prectx = preCanvas.getContext('2d');

    // render stuff to prectx
    ctx.putImageData(prectx.getImageData(0,0,preCanvas.width,preCanvas.height), 0, 0);
}
```

Why do the smaller resolution versions not get rendered to the canvas?

---

Unrelated to my main problem, how would I go about making sure that the rendering is interruptible by something like window.onresize?  And how might I go about optimizing my rendering routine to perform faster?

Comment: You're not giving it time to perform a paint event, use a brief delay after each drawing so the browser has time to update

Comment: I tried using setTimeout (you can see it in the commented out code at the bottom) with a 100ms delay but that didn't seem to do the trick.  

I looked at that section again and I realized that putting the canvas height and width modifications before the setInterval caused the problem.  If you add an answer, I can approve it for you.

Comment: I don't think I helped much, you were already almost there, just post a self answer which you can accept later on, just make sure it's as detailed as another users answer would be: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: When code is executing all changes to the DOM are buffered and will not be displayed until the current execution has ended. Using 
 `setTimeout(drawMandlebrot,0)` to call the render function  will cause the current execution to exit before running the function. The mandlebrot function will run and then exit only then will the new content be displayed. Event better is to use `requestAnimationFrame(drawMandlebrot)` when a function is called this way the back buffer is not display when the function exits but rather the back buffer is kept until the next display refreshj